# Best practice for testing android library projects?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I just recently started moving to Android Studio and Gradle and my first project is a small library which will now be build via gradle. Since at some point I want to push this to maven central I would like to integrate solid unit tests. I looked at some libraries like HoloColorPicker and Actionbarsherlock but none of them seems to test via gradle.

I really would like to be able to create classic JUnit 4 tests for simple things like testing utility classes which are not dependent on Android classes and Android tests for the rest. My library has no UI classes and I would like to prevent creating a "test application" which then can be instrumented (introduces more complexity and makes keeping tests working harder).
Basically it would be great if even the Android dependent tests would run on the JVM (for example with robolectric) instead of a device.

Of course I also need full IDE integration with Android Studio for things like finding typos directly, code completion, organizing imports, refactoring etc.

I read a lot of articles regarding these topics, but every solution had some severe disadvantages. Integrating Robolectric seems to be very hard and all plugins I found are outdated.
I hope one of you faced a similiar issue and has some advice how to handle unit testing in Android library projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've been working in two ways when it comes to testing, android tests and genymotion (which is faster then emulators or real devices), and robolectric. The weak side of android tests I find is that you're stuck with jUnit3 and that the instrumentation part is quiet verbose. The good part is that you get everything working right out of the box in Android Studio. I have also written a library with ca. 250 tests and this way was good enough (although it started to get slow in the end).

Robolectric's weak side is that it does not work right out of the box and need a little effort to set up. I havent been able to run tests through AS, but its quiet easy with the Terminal. Personally I use this plugin to run the tests

https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

as it enables me to run single test classes.

Comment: I already found the android-unit-test plugin. Unfortunately there seems to be no usable IDE integration. 
For now I will probably stick to classic Android testing und create "test Apps" for my libraries.

Comment: Yes, the IDE integration is very hacky ATM. If IDE integration is a must then I guess old fashioned android tests are the best way.

Personally I use terminal to execute my tests and view results in the browser ;-)